# Mongoose timeout does not apply

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to increase the connection timeout for mongoose, since my MongoDB takes some time to boot up.

```
// I have also tried
// var mongooseOptions = { replset: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS : config.mongodb.dbTimeout }}};
var mongooseOptions = { server: { socketOptions: { connectTimeoutMS: config.mongodb.dbTimeout }}};
logger.info('Establishing connection to MongoDB... (Timeout is ' + config.mongodb.dbTimeout + ')');
mongoose.connect(config.mongodb.uri, mongooseOptions, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        logger.error('Connection to MongoDB failed: ' + error);
        return;
    }
    ...
```

But the timeout is not applied, it immediately fails:

```
2015-04-24T10:43:10.156Z - info: Establishing connection to MongoDB... (Timeout is 300000)
2015-04-24T10:43:10.275Z - error: Connection to MongoDB failed: MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Edit: I am using Mongoose 4.0.1

Comment: Timeouts are for when the client can't connect. Your error is implying that it has connected but has been refused.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For testing, I have shut down the MongoDB. There is no MongoDB running. So it can't have been connected.

Comment: @MichaelKunzmann where you able to fix this ? I have the same problem